# how to android theme to show top bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I'm using :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

but I'm missing the top bar which has clock and notification center and battery icon 
(i don't know what this bar's name is)

So my question is: what is best theme to show the top bar working ?

I don't want the title bar or button bar which has back button and home button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to remove only `Title Bar` use but not the `Status Bar`

Do like this.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```